# Gutenberg default attributes are empty when accessing in edit

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

I'm quite new to Gutenberg and Wordpress and facing some issues with my attribute. When I'm trying to output the attribute data it is returning an empty object. Not quite sure why the default values aren't being applied?
Thanks in advance!

```
registerBlockType("mt/product-listing", {
  title: "Product",
  icon: "edit-page",
  category: "design",
  attributes: {
    content: { type: 'string' }
  }, 
  ...,
```

And when trying to access in edit:

```
 edit: (props) => {
    // Accessing props
    console.log("Edit", props);


    return (
      <div>
         <Products product={props.attributes} />
      </div>
    )
  },
```

Resulting output:

```
{
    "name": "mt/product",
    "isSelected": true,
    "attributes": {},
    "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
    "isSelectionEnabled": true,
    "context": {},
    "className": "wp-block-mt-product"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't defining any defaults in your `registerBlockType`

```json
[...]
attributes: {
    content: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'I am a string',
    },
},
[...]
```

Worth noting also that the attributes will only get saved in your final markup once they have a value - it won't save the defaults in the content.

Comment: Yep, totally correct. Failed to realize that it was specifically set by the deafult-key. 
Thank you so much.